# Multiple Camera view showing same camera feed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to show multiple views of camera, all showing same camera feed but in different views within one big view.
Just like the Nostalgio app on the appstore.

I've tried image picker controller as well as AVCapture Sessions nothing seems to work for me.

Any pointers/solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: is there a way to show multiple AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer ?

Comment: What is the problem, does it fail to compile? What did you try?

Comment: if i make two objects then One object show camera (grab camera) and other remain blank